# How to set 1 hour time window and then Do loop in SAS

Tags: sas

I've been searching for the answers for my question but couldn't find one so I post my question here.
I have a huge data set. Before I ask my question, I'll explain how it looks like and what I want to do.

```
**ID**   **Website**  **Datetime**        **Googlevisit**
A        Google       2014/06/01 16:50      1 
A        Facebook     2014/06/01 17:40      1
A        Yahoo        2014/06/01 18:00      0
A        Facebook     2014/06/01 18:10      0
A        Google       2014/06/01 19:00      1
B        Amazon       
B        Aol          
B        Facebook     
C        SouthWest
```

ID is individual ID.
Website is where each individual has browsed.
Datetime is when each individual has browsed the website.

What I want to do is I want to set an 1hour past interval from the current row time and then want to check if an individual has been to Google within 1hour or not. 
For example, if an individual A from 19:00 to 18:00 searched Google at least once within 1hour interval, the new value in the new column is 1.
Again, an individual A from 18:10 to 17:10 didn't search Google, so the value is 0. 
Again, an individual A from 18:00 to 17:00 didn't search Google, so the value is 0. 
Again, an individual A from 17:40 to 16:40 searched Google at least once within that interval, so the value is 1.

I wasn't that good at coding but I tired hard to get the solutions for this.

I tried this->

```
DATA A; SET A;
if Website='Google' then Googlevisit=1;
else Googlevisit=0;
where Datetime between INTNX('second',Datetime,-3600) and Datetime;
run;
```

also this too->

```
DATA A; SET A;
if Datetime=>INTNX('second',Datetime,-3600) and Datetime<=Datetime then do;
if Website='Google' then Googlevisit=1;
else Googlevisit=0;
end;
run;
```

I thought these two codes were going to capture the 1hour interval but didn't.
The output just shows that if the individual in a certain time visited google, the new value for that row becomes 1 or else, 0.
It would be appreciated if someone help me out with this. I feel so desperate since I have been trying to solve this more than one week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to keep information from one row to the next. You will have to `RETAIN` it.

```
data have;
input ID $ Website $  Datetime :ANYDTDTM16.;
datalines ;
A     Google       2014/06/01-16:50      
A     Facebook     2014/06/01-17:40     
A     Yahoo        2014/06/01-18:00     
A     Facebook     2014/06/01-18:10     
A     Google       2014/06/01-19:00 
;
run; 

data want;
    set have;
    by ID;

    retain googletime ;
    if first.id then googletime =. ;
    if Website='Google' then googletime=Datetime;

    Googlevisit = ( Datetime <= INTNX('second',googletime,3600));

run;
```

Retaining:
SAS processes the dataset row by row in sorted order.
`where Datetime between INTNX('second',Datetime,-3600) and Datetime;` does not give the desired result as you are always comparing the row with itself. By generating a new variable and retaining it, we can keep the original datetime value and compare it in the following rows. ( RETAIN is necessary as SAS will otherwise reset the new variable to missing with every iteration of the datastep).

`Googlevisit = ( Datetime <= INTNX('second',googletime,3600));` SAS computes this as condition a that can be either true or false and returns the value of 1/0 to the variable Googlevisit

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. The code worked perfect on my data set! I have two questions about your code. 1.How this code worked even though you didn't write down 'if then googlevisit=1, else googlevisit=0'. Specifically, how SAS recognized the new values should be either 1 or 0 even though you didn't make the code in that way?           2.So the SAS doesn't recognize setting the time interval from current row datetime to the past? because your code set the interval between the current row datetime and the 1 hour future.

Comment: 2. Direction of the interval was not the problem. I just chose a positive interval as we are comparing newer to older dates. See my edits to the answer regarding retaining a value. Your approach did not work as you were comparing the value of datetime to itself.